# custom jquery ui dialog cannot be closed automatically

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a main page with a button and 2 div "for dialog box",
1  has a loading image in it
the other  filled using dialog.load(url).

Because it takes many second to load the content div i show the loading wheel. and close it once the content div is loaded.

My problem is that I'm using jquery UI with a theme "which i don't know which one it is" and when i load the url in content the jquery-UI are applied to the loadingWheel div.

This cause the loadingWheel div to not close once the page is loaded.
I tried loading the page that i need to display and it wouldn't close.
I then tried loading an image and this time the loading wheel would close.

Unfortunately i cannot reproduce the bug on JFiddle because the theme i use is local :(.

Is there a way to force close a dialog box?

my code 'short version' in JSFiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/f82QX/

```
    $( document ).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#loadingWheel').dialog('open');

}).ajaxStop(function(){
     $('#loadingWheel').dialog('close');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is other way to close the dialog.

Try -

```
$('#loadingWheel').parent().remove();
```

Suggestion - check in developers' tool console if there is any error like - 'close call before initialize'. If that is the case, then you can try -

```
$('#loadingWheel').dialog().dialog('close');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I does give me an error only i can't really do much with it.            `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM46:6`

Comment: Try the two upper said approaches.

Comment: using   `$('#loadingWheel').parent().remove();` in the ajaxStop before / after the dialog('close') does not do anything nor did the dialog().dialog('close');

Comment: Decide to change my mouse cursor to "wait" and "default" instead. 
Thanks for your help Subha